# Make about: page think it is https (or chrome:// page safe for untrusted)

Tags: firefox-addon

I was wondering if it is possible to make Firefox think a page is `https`?

I have set up an about: page and used these flags to make it think it is `http`:

```
    getURIFlags: function(aURI) {
        return Ci.nsIAboutModule.URI_SAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CONTENT | Ci.nsIAboutModule.ALLOW_SCRIPT | Ci.nsIAboutModule.URI_MUST_LOAD_IN_CHILD;
    },
```

The `URI_SAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CONTENT` makes it be just like a regular webpage.

Is there anway to make it act like https? Because otherwise I can't get webrtc screensharing to work on it.

I also tried tricky things like `setCurrentURI` from framesccript to change the location to something else:

```
    var webNav = contentWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation);
    webNav.setCurrentURI(Services.io.newURI('https://mozilla.github.io/', null, null));
```

This also didn't work.

Or is there anyway to make chrome:// pages be URI_SAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CONTENT? I tried setting `contentaccessible=yes` in the manifest and that didn't do it:

```
content screencastify ./ contentaccessible=yes
locale screencastify en-US locale/en-US/
```